# How to get the signature of a C++ bind(...) expression

Tags: c++, function, boost, c++11, signature

I am trying to write a metafunction named signature_of which, given the type of a function (pointer), functor, or lambda, returns its signature.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/is_member_function_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/function_type.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/result_type.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/parameter_types.hpp>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
struct signature_of_member
{
    typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type result_type;
    typedef typename boost::function_types::parameter_types<F>::type parameter_types;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::pop_front<parameter_types>::type base;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::push_front<base, result_type>::type L;
    typedef typename boost::function_types::function_type<L>::type type;
};

template <typename F, bool is_class>
struct signature_of_impl
{
    typedef typename boost::function_types::function_type<F>::type type;
};

template <typename F>
struct signature_of_impl<F, true>
{
    typedef typename signature_of_member<decltype(&F::operator())>::type type;
};

template <typename F>
struct signature_of
{
    typedef typename signature_of_impl<F, std::is_class<F>::value>::type type;
};
```

It's pretty straightforward, with most of the real work being done by the boost::function_types library.
The general idea is:

- use std::is_class to discriminate
  between built-in functions (including
  lambdas) and functors
- for built-in function types, use boost::function_types::function_type to get its signature
- for functors, get the type of their operator(), get its signature, and doctor it to remove the "this" parameter

This works for built-in functions:

```
int f(int);
typedef signature_of<decltype(f)>::type Sig;  // Sig is int(int)
```

for lambdas:

```
auto f = [](int) { return 0; }
typedef signature_of<decltype(f)>::type Sig;  // Sig is int(int)
```

and for functors:

```
struct A
{
    int operator()(int);
};
typedef signature_of<A>::type Sig;  // Sig is int(int)
```

However, it doesn't work for bind() expressions (which are a special case of functors). If I try this:

```
#include <functional>
int g(int);
typedef signature_of<decltype(std::bind(g, 0))>::type Sig;
```

I get a compiler error:

```
In file included from test.cpp:3:0:
signature_of.hpp: In instantiation of 'signature_of_impl<
        _Bind<int (*(int))(int)>, true
    >':
signature_of.hpp:45:74:   instantiated from 'signature_of<
        _Bind<int (*(int))(int)>
    >'
test.cpp:21:52:   instantiated from here
signature_of.hpp:39:74: error: type of '& _Bind<
        int (*)(int)({int} ...)
    >::operator()' is unknown
```

The problem is that the operator() of the functor returned by bind() is a template, and so its type cannot be determined.

Is it possible to get the signature of a bind() expression another way?

Comment: VC10 cannot compile this, errors are stupid as usually (`error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::function_types::result_type<T>'`), it doesn't like this specialization: `typedef typename signature_of_member<decltype(&F::operator())>::type type;`

Comment: @Andy T: how do you convert to std::function without mentioning the template parameter of std::function, which *is* the signature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got more problems than the fact that a binder's operator() is templated, it also has an arbitrary count of parameters.  Remember that you're supposed to be able to invoke the result of bind with any number of extra arguments.  For example:

```
int f(int);

auto bound = boost::bind(f, _2);
```

`bound` may now be called with any number of arguments of 2 or more, only the second is actually forwarded on to the function.

So basically, as another answer said, this object has no signature.  It's signature is defined only by how it is used.

Comment: Good point, I actually didn't know you could use bind() this way.

Answer (score 4):

If the operator is templated, then it *doesn't have* a signature.

Comment: Or looking at it slightly differently, it doesn't have a unique signature. `operator()` can be instantiated with different template arguments, and they participate in the signature of that instantiation of `operator()`.

Comment: Yes, but if g has signature int(int), then conceptually, bind(g, 0) should have signature int(void). The fact that the std::bind implementation uses a templated operator() is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @HighCommander4: Conceptually? Who cares? The fact is, it isn't going to happen. If `bind` produces a functor with a templated operator(), you're screwed, and you can concept whatever you like, and it ain't gonna change that.

Comment: Sure, there's no way to do it by examining the operator(), but maybe there is another way, e.g. by examining the template parameter of the object returned by bind().

Comment: @HighCommander4: MSDN says that the return type is unspecified and only guarantees that it provides a `result_type` typedef. Infact, the operator() *must* be templated so as to perfectly forward it's arguments. I just checked MSVC10 and it thinks that the return type has no useful anything, essentially.